# Integrating @google-cloud/profiler in React App with Django Backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-profiler

I'm working on a project where I have a React front-end and a Django back-end. I need to integrate @google-cloud/profiler for specific functionalities in the React application. I've already set up my Django backend to interact with Google Cloud services.

Here's what I have so far:

- Django backend interacting with Google Cloud.
- React front-end using TypeScript.
- Now, I'm trying to integrate @google-cloud/profiler into my React app. I've tried a few things, but I'm facing challenges with the setup.

Here are my specific questions:

- What is the correct way to import and use @google-cloud/profiler in a React component?
- Are there any specific configurations I need to consider when using this library in a React app with a Django backend?
- How can I handle authentication and securely interact with Google Cloud services from the React app?
- I've reviewed the official documentation, but I'm looking for practical examples or advice from someone who has successfully integrated this library into a similar stack.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!